# surge protector when device turned off

Tags: voltage, surge-protection

Can a voltage spike hurt a plugged-in device even if the device turned off? (e.g. an air-conditioner that's always plugged but rarely in use)

And if so, would you recommend installing surge protector on such device?

Comment: Your house might already have a surge protector fitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory "yes", in practice "no."  What is the voltage spike?  Is it 10 volts too high?  Definitely "no".  Is it 1000 volts too high?  Well, definitely possibly.  A large spike could, for example, jump the contacts in a physical on-off switch, which may very well be rated only for 250V.  But without more details, there's no real way to answer.

Also, if the equipment is "always on" (e.g. has part of it that is always live, such as a remote-control circuit that is always "on" waiting to receive the "power on" button-press signal from a remote control), then yes, definitely a spike might hurt it (if the spike is "large enough").

But unless the equipment is bottom-of-the-barrel minimum-cost "junk", chances are the equipment is already inherently protected against most common "spikes" one is likely to encounter.